# Generating clean HTML markup with jQuery (like JSX)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've been a long-time jQuery user, and just started learning React. I really like how React handles HTML markup within Javascript using JSX, so I was wondering if there was a way to do something similar in jQuery?

For example, all my Ajax calls in jQuery return something that looks like this:

```
.done(data){
     var content = "";
     content += "<div class='watermelon'>";
     content += "<div class='green-shell'>";
     content += data.inside;
     content += "</div></div>";
     $("#div-element").html(content);
}
```

Is it possible to make it look something instead like:

```
.done(data){
     <div class='watermelon'>
         <div class='green-shell'>
             {data.inside}
         </div>
     </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use Underscores template like so:

```
var template = _.template('<div class=\"watermelon\">' + 
                            '<div class=\"green-shell\">' +
                              '<%=inside%>' +
                            '</div>' +
                          '</div>'
                         );
.done(data) {
  $("#div-element").html(template({inside: data.inside}));
}
```

Kindof sloppy still because it's not JSX.  If it is an option for you and you are beginning to really like React.  I would try and began rewriting the JQuery to React so you can fully take advantage of JSX/React instead of finding a way to write a JSX alternative in JQuery.  Just my advice as I was a big JQuery fan until I saw the advantages of the virtual DOM and such that React provides.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is been solved in ES2015. You can return [multiline string](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) with `backTick`. But as of now browser support is bad for this , so you need to use `babel` or something like that for transpiling .

```
.done(data){
   $("#div-element").html(
     `<div class='watermelon'>
         <div class='green-shell'>
            ${data.inside}
         </div>
     </div>`
   );
}
```